# Qooxdoo: _body sometimes null for qx.event.handler.Focus for mobile

Tags: javascript, qooxdoo

During startup of Qooxdoo framework its possible the user is already doing some user interface actions like mousemove event. In the constructor of "qx.event.handler.Focus" the document body is stored as reference to this._body, but that time the body is not yet ready loaded. Which means this._body will be null during the application session. In this case the focus and blurring of the fields will not work properly.
Instead of storing a reference to the body, it would be better to replace places where _body is used by _document.body.

Comment: Hi J Baan. Could yoou please provide us an example how this error occurs. When you're using the originally index.html or the loading mechanism everything will work fine.

Comment: In the head first we have a have a script tag pointing to url of qooxdoo.js, containing the whole qooxdoo bundle. One of the next script tags is a script making a new Qooxdoo Mobile application. However already during loading of the big Qooxdoo.js if I already move my mouse over the screen, then on window already a mouse move handler is triggered which load the Focus class and at that time the document.body is not yet set. I can load all the script tags in body of my start page, then it works, but that is not what I actually want.